# What does the parameter (..., -1) mean when reshaping an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes, reshape

I came across the following statement:

```
train_set_x.reshape(train_set_x.shape[0], -1).T
```

The `shape` of `train_set_x` is: `(209, 64, 64, 3)`

I thus believe that `shape[0]` is `209`, and `T` is the transpose?

I couldn't however understand the `reshape` statement above? What is `-1`?

Any clarifications on that is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -1 will take the remaining dimensions and flatten them into 1 dimension. So in the case of an array with shape `(209, 64, 64, 3)` calling:

```
arr.reshape(209, -1)
```

would result in a matrix of shape `(209, 12288)` or (209, 64 * 64 * 3)

```
 >>> a = np.zeros([209, 64, 64, 3])
 >>> a.reshape(209, -1).shape
 (209, 12288)
```

If your code is for a 64 x 64 RGB image, you will end up with each image being reshaped into one long vector.

Also, note that there can be *only one -1* in the new shape that the array will be reshaped into.